# Limiting text field entry length

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have been trying to limit the length of text entry for one of my text fields however I have been having issues getting it to function.

This is the code I am using:

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
        let newLength = countElements(budgetNameTextField.text!) + countElements(string!) - range.length
        return newLength <= 10 //Bool
}
```

I also have UITextFieldDelegate:

```
class PersonalisationTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Could anyone let me know what I have missed? The text field just functions as normal and doesn't limit the text length.

Comment: That code works for me. Are you sure you have your delegate wired up correctly?

Comment: Ah, thank you. I did indeed have the delegate connected incorrectly.